JUnit test suite custom selector
I have a custom annotation that maps my tests to a Jira key.
@Jira("jira-T123")

I want to create a test suite selector that takes a list of Jira keys as a parameter, it then runs any test annotated with @Jira whose value is contained in the selectors list.
@Suite
@SelectPackages(<test package>)
@SelectJiraKeys({ "jira-T123", "jira-T124"})
public class JiraKeySuite {

Not sure where to get started.
Appreciate the help
Update
As recommended in the comments; I tried to see if I could leverage @Tag to create the suite. In order to avoid duplication I figured I could just change my current annotation to automatically add the appropriate Tag.
@Tag("")
@Test
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Jira {

/**
 * Jira test case keys.
 *
 * @return
 */
@AliasFor(annotation = Tag.class, attribute = "value")
String value();
}

But unfortunately there is no support for composed annotations with annotation attribute overrides as mentioned:

https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/3103
Junit meta annotations. How to provide parameters into inner annotation?

I think the only options are:

An Aspect to decorate test cases with the @Tag("value")
Custom Test Engine to extend the DiscoverySelectorResolver


A simple hack: Use tags which are directly supported.

@johanneslink I think you're approach might be right. The more I look into it, the less I think my solution is going to work.  The org.junit.platform.suite.commons.SuiteLauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder is where the suite discovery is built and there doesn't appear to be any mechanism to cleanly extend or customize it. I'm going to look to see if my current annotation can generate the tag. Thanks for engaging!
